# Android Java Record Video and embed Text

Tags: java, android

I'm want to create a Android App that record video using Surface view. The app must record a video including an added TextView showing the Time and date like a watermark.

Tge only thing that I'm not sure is if it posible to record a SurfaceView and include in it both camera and Textview to make a video from it?